# Who gave the Pelican Nebula its name?

Tags: nebula, naming

[IC 5070](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelican_Nebula) is a nebula in Cygnus that is also sometimes called the Pelican Nebula. Who gave it this name?

Comment: Someone prior to Feb 1997 https://web.archive.org/web/19970227213617/http://voltaire.csun.edu/north_america.html